# Center glyphicon content

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I using Google Chrome Inspector and if you select the before pseudo of the glyphicon you will see that there is empty space at the right. How I can center the glyphicon?

I tried to set text align but it doesn't work.

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
<style>.glyphicon { font-size: 120px; }</style>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sps01dsd/embedded/result/)

Updated link [jsFiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/sps01dsd/1)

[image: Glyphicon]

Comment: Updated link http://jsfiddle.net/sps01dsd/1/

Comment: It might be a kerning problem within the glyphicons font file, if you try a single a-z characters in an inline element you will se that they are correct center aligned.

Comment: @Luizgrs you right, I believe most of them are correct but some other not, if you try glyphicon-minus it even worse. I think the only way is to adjust manually. Will wait  for better solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I gave `letter spacing` for pseudo element and it did the trick. I tried changing the `font-size` and I see that white space is not appearing.

```
.glyphicon:before{
   letter-spacing: -0.085em;
 }
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MasoomS/1z79r22y/

Comment: this is the best answer by far.. I will accept it but will wait another few days to give the bounty

Answer (score 4):

I believe the root problem here is with the SVGs that the icon font was built from.  I've built icon fonts before from SVGs and saw this exact same behavior.  If the symbol wasn't centered within its SVG `viewbox`, you'd get a glyph that was off-center like you've observed.

Developing a code-based solution would get super messy, because you'd have to individually account for each glyph that isn't centered, and then your offsets would have to be relative to the size of the icon so the offsets scale with the `font-size` of the icon.  It's certainly do-able, but it seems like the sort of thing that would be a headache to maintain.

I would recommend one of the following:

- Accept the glyphicon set for what it is (a free icon font) and live with its imperfections
- Look for another icon font that doesn't have this same issue--be willing to pay for a license
- Create your own icon font so you can ensure that all glyphs are centered

Answer (score 2):

**Almis** Hi there. Your demo code is only using **just** the `span` holding the glyphicon it has no **Width** to center within.

As soon as you do something like this it will center.

```
<div class="text-center">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
</div>
<br>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus col-xs-12 text-center"></span>
```

Here is a **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AngularJR/sps01dsd/2/)**.

[image]

Comment: Hi, your example its exactly same with mine, if you take a ruler you will see that the y-axis is exactly the same. Check the updated jsfiddle to see what I mean

Comment: Hi, sorry I did not get it clear the first time. Re looked at you new fiddle and I can see what you mean now. Have a look at this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/AngularJR/sps01dsd/3/). There is even a difference between the plus icon and the minus icon. The **minus** looks to have space the the left and the **plus** icon has the space to the right as you pointed out.

Comment: yeah I know, if we can't do anything then the author of this glyphicons should fix it

Comment: Hi, I asked uncle google, but didn't find anything about this.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the class `my-style-icon` to the icon and add this to your CSS:

```
.my-style-icon {
    font-size: 120px;
    display: block;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: The span is in the center but the before pseudo is not (I should mention that in the question)

Comment: Please enter the full code, all i see in the jsfiddle is the icon html and some  useless css.

Comment: I didnt do much I just wanted to center glyphicon in a box but because of that pseudo before it doesn't look that it's in the middle. I can use padding or margin to fix that but I though that there might be better solution. Check the updated link

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick for you:

```css
vertical-align: middle; 
margin: 0 auto;
```

Comment: not working, can you update my jsfiddle? maybe I doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Hello **Almis**.

```
.glyphicon {
      font-size: 120px;
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

Just replace the  .glyphicon class with above css code.

Enjoy..

Comment: Didn't work, please update the jsfiddle if you think it works

Answer (score 1):

As you can see its clearly a problem by the author adding some white space, the only why to fix this is by setting the width manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of the empty space on the right of the glyph by playing with the `letter-spacing` attribute:

```
.glyphicon {
    font-size: 120px;
    letter-spacing: -9px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I normally use max-width (and width, if I want all icons in a list to have the same size) to deal with such issues.

As per your jsFiddle:

```
max-width:222px;
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f4bvujfx/).

Answer (score 1):

The reason this can't be fixed in any other way other than a hack is because the glyphicon itself isn't centered inside it's own container, meaning when it was designed in it's matrix it wasn't fully centered.

You will have to 'hack' it with shivs stated above (letter spacing, negative margin, etc) but it's resolution dependent.

However to VERTICALLY center it you can remove the padding, and use line-height equal to your container's height

Answer (score 1):

Use `font-awesome`, it's `+` is perfectly centered, with no kerning problems. Use `display:flex` on the parent, in combination with `margin:auto` on the child (i.e. icon). It results in a perfect alignment.
Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rpad/sps01dsd/13/)

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="add" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.fa-plus {
   margin: auto;
   font-size: 10em;
}
#add {
   border: 5px dashed black;
   border-radius: 25px;
   display: flex;
}
```